# Transpose a matrics in Julia without Transpose operator ( ' ) and extra packages

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia, transpose

I am relatively new to Julia and i only had C programming experience so far. Now i wanted to make my own transpose function, however i'am kinda stuck on how i should make the loop.
I tried `hcat` to concat the rows to a `reverse(size(a))` array. This method works in the console but i dont know how to put it ina loop.
My code so far:

```
function transpose(a::Array{Int64,2})
    transM = zeros(reverse(size(a)))

    for i in [1:length(a)]
        for j in [1:length(a[1,1])]
            transM[j,i] = a[i,j]
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it solved, i just had the wrong idea on how to iterate through the array.

```
function transpose(a::Array{Int64,2})
     transM = zeros(Int64,reverse(size(a)))
     (r,c) = size(a)
     save = []
     for i in 1:c
       for j in 1:r
           transM[i,j] = a[j,i]
      end
      save = transM
  end
  return save
end
```

Comment: Should be no need for `save`. Nor to zero the array, you can write `function transpose(a::Matrix); (r,c) = size(a); transM = similar(a, (c, r);` and it'll work for any element type.

Comment: Also, note that this is `permutedims(a)`. The difference is that `a'` is lazy, and that it is recursive, e.g. applies `'` to complex numbers within the array.

Comment: ...and that `permutedims` works on all kind of matrices, while `'` applies only to numerical ones...

Comment: @mcabbott thanks for the tipp, however i need to save it. I tried it without save and if i print the function it returns nothing. Am i misunderstanding how the returns of a loop works?

Comment: A for loop returns `nothing`. But you can just return `transM` after the loop.

Comment: 1) `permutedims` does this
2) list comprehensions `m,n = size(mat); [mat[j,i] for i in 1:n, j in 1:m]`